# error while installing pip in windows10

Tags: pip, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have tried to install pip using command  :
        `sudo apt install python-pip`

but after installing a few files and asking for admin rights, it gets stuck at at a file, giving the error -

"Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.4.0-77.98
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-77.98_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
"

I am using python 3.5.2 on Windows10 (bash)

PS : yes, i'm  total noob . But i really want to do some python .

Comment: The download target doesn't exist for some reason. Could you run `sudo apt update` and try again? This refreshes the package lists from the server.

Comment: `sudo` on `Windows 10`? Are you sure u r not on linux? You should try running  `cmd` as  administrator instead...

Comment: @Plirkee He's using WSL probably

Comment: @Lennart You are probably right ... however, since on `Windows`, could have just installed `python` for `windows`...

Comment: @Lennart that was right on spot. THANKS!! (if you write it as an answer this question will be resolved and you can get my upvote too :p) 
And yeah, I'm using windows subsystem for linux. 
-Plirkee any additional benefits of downloading python_for_windows  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the package lists are out of date and point to a version that doesn't exist on the server anymore. Just run `sudo apt update` (which fetches the latest package list from the server, but doesn't update the package itself) and try installing it again.